# How to find all files in subfolders that user does not have full access to?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, user

I am looking for a command that will list me all files that a certain user, e.g. "userA" does NOT have full access rights to. All files in all subfolders.
Is this possible?

Background: at work I am forced to work as non-admin, as most others do also. Unfortunately, our IT support is utterly incompetent.
I had to work with a second user authentication during a short term delegation and despite those files being mine, they were stored with access rights only to that user.

Now I need access to those files and our IT support is unable to simply change me to the owner for all files in all subfolders. They want a list of files so they can change them one by one -.-

I am certain that this is the dumbest way to do so, but I have no admin rights so I have no choice.

I hope someone here knows the simple command either in CMD or PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner should do that:

```
icacls C:\path\ /t /c | findstr C: | findstr /v (F)
```

Explanation:

- [icacls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)
  will list all files and their permissions
- the first
  [findstr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)
  command will isolate the lines containing file names, omitting other lines
- the second findstr will find lines that do not contain "(F)"
  that stands for full-control.